# Laravel chainable where clause is not working

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

i have blogs table in the DB which has tag,tag1,tag2 columns, i'm trying to get all the blogs related to current blog in the show page if any of the 3 tags are similar to it , i'm using the code below but the problem is that i'm getting the main blog with related which i don't want.
i'm using where not but its not working

```
function blogShow($id) {
        
        $blog = Blog::find($id);

        $tags = [$blog->tag,$blog->tag1,$blog->tag2];

        $related = Blog::select("*")
        ->where('id', '!=', $id)
        ->whereIn('tag',$tags)
        ->orWhereIn('tag1',$tags)
        ->orWhereIn('tag2',$tags)
        ->get();

        return view('main.blogs.show',compact('blog','related'));
    }
```

PS: when i use  -> toSql i'm getting the current query :
**"select * from `blogs` where `id` != ? and `tag` in (?, ?, ?) or `tag1` in (?, ?, ?) or `tag2` in (?, ?, ?)"**
which seems correct ,the $id value is correct as well so where is the problem .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make subcondition like this

```
function blogShow($id) {
    
    $blog = Blog::find($id);

    $tags = [$blog->tag,$blog->tag1,$blog->tag2];

    $related = Blog::select("*")
    ->where('id', '!=', $id)
    ->where(function($q) {
      $q->whereIn('tag',$tags)
        ->orWhereIn('tag1',$tags)
        ->orWhereIn('tag2',$tags);
    })
    ->get();

    return view('main.blogs.show',compact('blog','related'));
}
```

However, I highly recommend that you use the nicer way for tags. for example you can create a `tags` table and create a relation table `blog_tag` with `blog_id` and `tag_id` so you have unlimited tags and excluding duplicate tags